# Cannot specialize template when const is involved

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm dealing with a template, it's very simple. This is the current structure:

```
//primary template
template<typename T> 
const T bit_cast(const BitExpr* p);    

//specialization
template<> 
inline const BitBinExpr* bit_cast<BitBinExpr*>(const BitExpr* p) {
    if (p->type == XOR || p->type == AND)
        return static_cast<const BitBinExpr*>(p);
    return nullptr;
}
// more specializations follow
```

But Visual Studio insists that this is not valid. However, when the parameter and return types were *not* `const`, this worked just fine. How can I convince VS to accept this code?

Comment: If you'll always be returning pointers, wouldn't using `const T* bit_cast` in the primary template just work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have cropped up a lot lately. These two types are not the same

```
const BitBinExpr* // BitBinExpr is constant
```

and

```
typedef BitBinExpr* T;
const T           // pointer is constant
```

Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
template<typename T> const T bit_cast(const BitExpr* p);    
template<> inline const BitBinExpr *const bit_cast<const BitBinExpr *const>(const BitExpr* p) {
    if (p->type == XOR || p->type == AND)
        return static_cast<const BitBinExpr*>(p);
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: `const BitBinExpr const *` is nonsensical. Did you mean `BitBinExpr const* const`? If so, that won't work any better that what the OP already has.

Comment: How (frustrating and) surprising. Is there any way to express the correct logic, or will I be forced to pass a const template parameter?

Comment: @ildjarn Yes I did, edited. Why do you say it won't work? It's seems to be working for me.

Comment: @jahhaj : It won't work unless you change the type that is being specialized, which is too drastic a change to be useful IMO.

Comment: Well I wonder if the OP really wants `template<typename T> const T bit_cast(const BitExpr* p);` just `template<typename T> T bit_cast(const BitExpr* p);` is perfectly fine.

Comment: I wanted to avoid having to pass `const` as the template parameter. It's a bitch to chase down every call site. But I guess that's not possible.